# Add values in a cell R

Tags: r, dataset, cell, addition

I got an column with the types of beds that are in a hotelroom, but I want to know how many people can sleep in this room. My dataset looks like this:

```
        nrofP
         2||2
         3||3
            1
            6
         1||1
2||2||2||2||2
            5
      2||2||1
```

My expected outcome is:

```
nrofP
    4
    6
    1
    6
    2
   10
    5
    5
```

I hope you might know a way to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rooms <- c("2||2", "3||3","1", "6", "1||1", "2||2||2||2||2", 
"5","2||2||1")

occupancy <- do.call("c", lapply(strsplit(rooms, "\\|\\|"), function(x) 
{
sum(as.numeric(x))
}))
occupancy
```

Comment: similar to my approach.  Cool stuff

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lazyeval)

df <- data.frame(nrofP = c("2||2", "3||3", "1", "2||2||1"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$nrofP <- lapply(gsub("||", "+", df$nrofP, fixed = T), function(x) lazy_eval(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering nrofP as a vector.

```
sapply(nrofP,function(x) sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub('\\|\\|',' ',x),' ')))))
```